# Why this.setState does not update handle delete data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

could any React expert here please helps me answer this weird issue I have with my react component?
I am trying to create a function to remove an item in an array, however, the `setState` does not update new array but `console.log` shows the array is correctly updated with the items properly removed.

```
constructor (props) {
    super (props);

    this.state = {
        data: dummyData,
        chosenData:[],
        chosenOption:{}
    }
}

onDeleteOptionButtonClick = (id, titleId) => {
    const data = this.state.data.map(item => item.id === titleId ? {...item, possibleAnswers: item.possibleAnswers.filter(i => i.id !== id)} : item)
    this.setState({ data }, () => {console.log('log of data from state', this.state.data[0].possibleAnswers)})
    console.log('log of data from data',data[0].possibleAnswers)
}
```

here is the picture of the console.log
[image]

as you can see that the const data properly updates new array with the item removed, but the state stays the same.
Please help, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please Use this.setState inside the filter function itself.

Comment: how could that be possible in my case?